# mongodump --oplog on empty db throws segmentation fault?

Tags: mongodb, segmentation-fault, mongodump

I installed `mongodb`from scratch from the 10gen source on a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 Digital Ocean image:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
sudo apt-get -qq update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

When I do `mongodump` I get a segmentation fault:

root@willmit:~# /usr/bin/mongodump --oplog

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Mon Aug 19 10:33:47.394 all dbs
Mon Aug 19 10:33:47.395     local.oplog.$main to dump/oplog.bson
Segmentation fault
```

When create a dummy db with one collection and one document, it works as expected, also when I delete the dummy db again.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Question, does it happen without --oplog?  Should be easy to reproduce, just curious.

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce this issue? If so, can you include your version of mongodump (`mongodump --version`) and MongoDB git tag (`db.serverBuildInfo().gitVersion` in the `mongo` shell)? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem so far; dumping with a empty database in either MongoDB 2.2 or 2.4 reports: "No operations in oplog. Please ensure you are connecting to a master.".

Comment: Sorry, no. Not able to reproduce anymore.